# Subset in the data frame rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with 30 rows and 4 columns (namely, `x, y, z, u`). It is given below.

```
mydata = data.frame(x = rnorm(30,4), y = rnorm(30,2,1), z = rnorm(30,3,1), u = rnorm(30,5))
```

Further, I have a sequence values, which represent row number in my data frame.

```
myseq = c(seq(1, 30, by = 5))
myseq
[1]  1  6 11 16 21 26
```

Now, I wanted to compute the `prob` values for each segment of 99 rows.

```
filt= subset(mydata[1:6,], mydata[1:6,]$x < mydata[1:6,]$y & mydata[1:6,]$z < mydata[1:6,]$u
filt
prob = length(filt$x)/30
prob
```

Then I need to compute the above `prob` for `1:6`,.., `27:30` and so on . Here, I have only 6 `prob` values. So, I can do one by one. If I have 100 values it would be tedious. Are there any way to compute the `prob` values?.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW: in `subset(DF[1:99,], ...)`, use `DF[1:99,]` in the first argument, not again, ala

```
subset(DF[1:99,], cumsuml < inchivaluel & cumsumr < inchivaluer)
```

Think about how to do this in a `list`.

1. The first step is to break your data into the `va` starting points. I'll start with a list of the indices to break it into:

   ```
   inds <- mapply(seq, va, c(va[-1], nrow(DF)), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
   ```

   this now is a list of sequences, starting with `1:99`, then `100:198`, etc. See `str(inds)` to verify.
2. Now we can subset a portion of the data based on each element's vector of indices:

   ```
   filts <- lapply(inds, function(ind) subset(DF[ind,], cumsuml < inchivaluel & cumsumr < inchivaluer))
   ```
3. We now have a list of vectors, let's summarize it:

   ```
   results <- sapply(filts, function(filt) length(filt$cumsuml)/length(alpha))
   ```

Bottom line, it helps to think about how to break this problem into lists, examples at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272.

BTW: instead of initially making a list of indices, we could just break up the data in that first step, ala

```
DF2 <- mapply(function(a,b) DF[a:b,], va, c(va[-1], nrow(DF)), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
filts <- lapply(DF2, function(x) subset(x, cumsuml < inchivaluel & cumsumr < inchivaluer))
results <- sapply(filts, function(filt) length(filt$cumsuml)/length(alpha))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. In the above example, lets consider only first two columns. `filts <- lapply(DF2, function(x) subset(x, cumsuml < inchivaluel))`. Using `subset`, Am  I able to insert 1 if the statement true or insert 0 if the statement is false? Since, I want to sum all the rows in each segment of `DF2`. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried in is way. `filts <- lapply(DF2, function(x) subset(x, ifelse(cumsuml < inchivaluel, 1, 0)))`. But I am getting an error message.

Comment: The actions of `subset`ing and *changing/assigning* are completely different in data-terms. `subset` filters the rows (and optionally columns with `select=`), it has nothing to do with value changing or assignment. Where you do want to actually insert this 0 or 1?

Comment: Instead of eliminating the row,  I need to assign 0 or 1 in the `DF2`.

Comment: Instead of eliminating the row, I need to assign 0 if the argument is false or 1 if the argument is true in the DF2

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do this one. I used the ifelse argument in the data frame.

Comment: *Where* in `DF2` do you want to assign it? Do you want a new column, or modify an existing one?

Comment: Yes in  `DF2`. I add the new column in `DF`.